# Проблемы при очистке файлов на сервере с помощью PHP (циклом)

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста! При загрузке файлов на файлообменик все проходит нормально, но после того как я реализовал функцию очистки старых файлов при превышении максимально допустимого размера файлового хранилища мой цикл не падает, но чистит все файлы, а мне надо чтобы чистка происходила до определенного значения:

Это ссылка на мой файлообменник: http://test.afc.ru/exchange/index.php.

```
<?
    $path = 'storage'; // папка которую буду сканировать
    $beforeDir = scandir('storage'); // Получить список файлов и каталогов, расположенных по указанному пути до удаления старого файла
    echo "<br><p style='margin-left: 75px; color: blue;'><i>Содержимое папки <b>storage</b> до очистки:</i><br>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($beforeDir); $i++)
        echo "<span style='text-align: left; margin-left: 250px; color: green;'>$i. <i>$beforeDir[$i]</i></span>"."<br />";
    //print_r($beforeDir);
    //echo $dir[3];

echo "$maxFileSize - максимальный размер файлового хранилища допустим: 10МБ<br>";
echo "$filesize - размер первого загруженного файла доупстим: 5Мб<br>";
echo "$fileSize - размер файлового хранилища на текущий момент допустим он превысил: 20Мб<br><br>";

// Функция удаления файлов
if($fileSize > $maxFileSize){ // если размер файлового хранилища на текущий момент превысил максимальный размер

$MFS = $maxFileSize; 
$FS = $fileSize;

echo "$MFS - NEW максималка<br>"; // так для себя
echo "$FS - NEW общий вес<br>"; // так для себя

/* запускаем цикл удаления файлов при превышении максимальный размер файлового хранилища*/
while ($FS > $MFS){ // удалять пока вес файлового хранилища на текущий момент больше максимального
    $path = 'storage'; //указываю дирректорию
    $beforeDir = scandir('storage'); //сканирую дирректорию 
    if (unlink("storage/$beforeDir[3]")) //вытаскиваю из массива 4 элемент и удаляю сэтим именем файл в папке storage, поскольку первые 3 это: 0. .; 1. ..; 2. .htaccess;
        echo "<span style='text-align: center; color: red;'>Файл: $beforeDir[3] - удален!</span>"; 
    else 
        echo "<span style='text-align: center; color: red;'>Папка <b>storage</b> пуста!</span>";
/* снова проверяю директорию на общий размер ФХ на текущий момент */
    function getFilesSize(){ // Функция определения размера папки
        $path = 'storage'; //указываю дирректорию
        $FS = 0; // пока не понял зачем с нуля начинать, брал код из инета
        $dir = scandir($path); // Получить список файлов и каталогов, расположенных по указанному пути
        foreach($dir as $file){ // цикл так и не понял шо делает, но и не очень то и хотел, главное, что работает!
            if (($file!='.') && ($file!='..'))
                if(is_dir($path . '/' . $file))
                    $FS += getFilesSize($path.'/'.$file);
                else
                    $FS += $FS($path . '/' . $file);
        }
        return $FS; // Возвращает значение "размер файлов в Кбайтах"
    }
    $FS = (int)((getFilesSize()/1024)/1024); // Округление до Мбайтов*/
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы делал не так.

Если у вас хранилище, то вероятно, оттуда качают.

Так как вам нужно, чтоб у вас было как можно больше людей, значит у вас должно лежать то, что качают.

То есть. При каждой скачке файла (на худой конец при показе страницы с сылкой) вы делаете +1 с счетчик того файла. В примере, счетчик, это файл .rande.ИМЯФАЙЛА лежащий в той же папке, что и качаемый.

```
function rangesort ($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['range'] > $b['range'])
       return 1;
    else
       return -1;
}

function getFilesSize($path)
{
  global $files;

  $dir = scandir($path); 
    foreach($dir as $file){ 
        if (substr($file,0,1) != '.')
    {
            if(is_dir($path . '/' . $file))
                getFilesSize($path.'/'.$file);
            else
    {
                $files[$path . '/' . $file]['size'] = filesize($path . '/' . $file);
                $files[$path . '/' . $file]['range'] = file_get_contents($path . '/.range.' . $file);
    }
     }
    }
}

$files = array();

getFilesSize('full_storage_path_recomend');

usort($files, "rangesort");
```

Потом вы запускаете *foreach($files as $fullfilename => $attribs)* по этому массиву и удаляете по очереди наименее популярные файлы, пока не вернетесь за лимит.

Кстати для определения, достигли ли вы дзена, не нужно каждый раз проходится по циклу.
Достаточно один раз посчитать общий размер, а потом, после каждого удаления отнимать из общего размер, то, что удалили.

Если у вас по каким-то причинам нет возможности сделать подсчет, то общая идея - сначала создать масив, потом удалять - остаётся. Более того, чем больше у вас файлов, тем быстрее по итогу будет это работать (за счет большого уменьшения запусков циклов).
Можно не сортировать, а можно удалять самые старые. Или самые большие....

Полный код писать не буду) Тренеруйтесь.

Comment: Спасибо, огромное! Жаль только наградить не могу, я пока зеленый :)